# Inquiry about NumPy boolean arrays / indexing with boolean arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

```
import numpy as np

G1 = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11]],)
G1_Compare = G1 > 4
print(G1[G1_Compare])
```

Output:

```
[ 5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
```

I do understand what this does, but I just don't understand what is the operation happening in here.

What is exactly happening behind the scenes?

Also, why doesn't it print the false elements?

Comment: Which operation is the problem?

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing

Answer (score 1):

**Conceptual understanding of `G1 > 4`:**

`G1` is a shape `(3,4)` `numpy` array.

In `G1 > 4`, `G1` is participating as an operand in a comparison operation (`>`).

The other operand is `4`, which is not an array at all, and has no dimensions.

Now, [Broadcasting](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.broadcasting.html#basics-broadcasting) occurs.

Due to broadcasting, conceptually, the scalar `4` is broadcast into a shape `(3,4)` array consisting of just several `4`s as its elements.

So, now, conceptually speaking, the comparison operation `>` occurs **element-wise** between two similarly shaped arrays, each of shape `(3,4)`.

This results in a boolean array (`G1_Compare`), of shape `(3,4)`, consisting of `True` and `False` values. The `True` value occurs at those element-coordinates where the corresponding element of `G1` is greater than that of the broadcasted array consisting of `4`s.

Note that broadcasting of array does not actually create any new array (even temporarily) with the broadcasted shape. It is only a concept or metaphor to explain/understand the defined behavior and the result. Internally, `numpy` uses index manipulations to achieve the effect of broadcasting, without actually creating any new arrays in the broadcasted shape.

**Conceptual understanding of `G1[G1_Compare]`:**

Here, [boolean indexing](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) occurs.

Your question "why doesn't it print the false elements?" doesn't really make sense -- what would be the point of using a boolean index if it were to select the `True`-position elements as well as the `False`-position elements? The whole point of using a boolean index is to select and return the elements in the `True` positions, and exclude the elements in the `False` positions.